# Scope of enum in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, enums

Why are enum values accessible outside the block in which enum is defined in C, but not in C++?

Consider the following C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct mystruct
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, STRING} type;
    int integer;
    float floating_point;
} tu;

/* Why is INT accessible here? */
int main()
{
    tu.type = INT;
    tu.integer = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine in C.

But in C++ it fails in compilation.

```
#include <iostream>
struct mystruct
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, STRING} type;
    int integer;
    float floating_point;
} tu;

/* Why is INT accessible here? */
int main()
{
    tu.type = INT;
    tu.integer = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

> [Error] 'INT' was not declared in this scope

Are enum and scope rules different in C and C++?

Comment: learn about "namespace"

Comment: @meet C++ has class scope. See my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In C, there is simply no rule for scope for enums and struct. The place where you define your enum doesn't have any importance.

In C++, define something inside another something (like an enum in a class) make this something belong to the another something.

If you want to make your enum global in C++, you will have to define it outside your class, or access from your struct path:

```
#include <iostream>
struct mystruct
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, STRING} type;
    int integer;
    float floating_point;
} tu;

int main()
{
    tu.type = mystruct::INT; // INT is not in global scope, I have to precise it.
    tu.integer = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This works in this exemple, because you are using a `struct`, where everything is `public` by default. Be careful; you can access your enum type and values from outside your struct or your class only if the enum is in a `public` scope, as any field or function.

Comment: You're a bit too harsh on C. It definitely has scopes for names, block scopes such as `{ int i; }`. But that's specific to functions.

Comment: The problem with C is that it doesn't have scopes for anything for which in C++ you'd use `::` operator — because there's no such operator in C.

Comment: *The place where you define your enum doesn't have any importance.* What do you mean? I cannot put the definition after the variable I'm using.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Enumeration defined in function block is not visible outside that scope in C.

Comment: @Rusland, you mean the benefit of C?  ;-)  Joking aside, what is the benefit of using `::` over an underscore?

Answer (score 19):

The main difference is that opposite to C, C++ has a class scope.

In C (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 4 Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its
>   declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or
>   type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any
>   block or list of parameters, the identifier has **file scope**, which
>   terminates at the end of the translation unit.

Thus in this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct mystruct
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, STRING} type;
    int integer;
    float floating_point;
} tu;

/* Why is INT accessible here? */
int main()
{
    tu.type = INT;
    tu.integer = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

Enumerators INT, FLOAT, STRING are declared outside any block scope and therefore have the file scope.

In C++ there is defined a separate scope - class scope:

3.3.7 Class scope

> 1 The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>   1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only
>   of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration,
>   but also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   exception-specifications, and brace-or-equal-initializers of
>   non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

and

> 2 **The name of a class member shall only be used as follows:**
>
> — in the scope of its class (as described above) or a class derived
>   (Clause 10) from its class,
>
> — after the . operator applied to an expression of the type of its
>   class (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class,
>
> — after the -> operator applied to a pointer to an object of its class
>   (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class,
>
> — after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to the name of
>   its class or a class derived from its class.

Take into account that (9.2 Class members)

> 1 ...Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3),
>   nested types, and **enumerators**.

Thus in this program

```
#include <iostream>
struct mystruct
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, STRING} type;
    int integer;
    float floating_point;
} tu;

/* Why is INT accessible here? */
int main()
{
    tu.type = INT;  // Invalid access of class member
    tu.integer = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

You shall access class member `INT` in one of the following ways.

```
    tu.type = mystruct::INT;
```

or

```
    tu.type = tu.INT;
```

or even like

```
    tu.type = ( &tu )->INT;
```

Answer (score 7):

The answers given by Vlad and Arachtor are good as far as they go, but there is a question they do not address: why C++ does it differently. If someone is familiar with Stroustrup's book, they may be able to improve this, but I suppose:

- C was designed long ago to be fairly easy to compile, while C++ aims to make programming more reliable by using OO, whose main ideal is “in one place, tell the user of a construct all they need to know to use it and no more”; this has the often unspoken benefit of bringing together what belongs together.
- This leads to the decisions to use type definitions to limit the scope of some definitions, and to place constructs within a hierarchy of namespaces.
- By restricting the scope of a nested enum it is possible to use shorter names without risk of ambiguity or clashes.